# Wait for multiple XHR requests to the same url or endpoint

Tags: cypress

In Cypress, I have multiple requests that will match my `cy.route()` declaration. I want to make sure more than one request is made on the route. How do I tell Cypress to wait for multiple XHR requests to the same url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-wait-for-multiple-XHR-requests-to-the-same-url):

You should set up an **alias** (using [.as()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html)) to a single [cy.route()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html) that matches all of the XHRs. You can then [cy.wait()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html) on it multiple times. Cypress keeps track of how many matching XHR requests there are.

```
cy.server()
cy.route('users').as('getUsers')
cy.wait('@getUsers')  // Wait for first GET to /users/
cy.get('#list>li').should('have.length', 10)
cy.get('#load-more-btn').click()
cy.wait('@getUsers')  // Wait for second GET to /users/
cy.get('#list>li').should('have.length', 20)
```

Comment: if i need to make a call ton an endpoint for 30 elements and for each one of then i need to do an other call, i can not use this solution. Is there a way to wait for a determined number of alias?

Comment: see my answer @ErnestoAlfonso

Comment: What if you dont know how many aliases there are? I see there is an undocumented @alias.all that i can't get to work.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to pass in an array of aliases.

```
cy.wait(["@graphql", "@graphql"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
cy.wait("@Request1");
cy.wait("@Request2");
cy.wait(0);
cy.wait("@Request2");
```