# How to wait for two parallel XHR requests in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I know that it is possible to wait for multiple XHR requests on the same url as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472827/wait-for-multiple-xhr-requests-to-the-same-url-or-endpoint). However, I would like to wait for two requests running in parallel.

```
cy.wait('@users')
cy.wait('@users')
```

When I add two waits as shown above, the second one sometimes timeouts when they finish very closely together, as it basically misses the XHR.

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 30000ms for the 1st response to the route: 'users'. No response ever occurred.
```

I do not like the introduction of flakiness. Is there a better way to write this that I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a way to target each individual request more specifically, or are the URLs for the two requests *exactly* the same? For example, if you're waiting for `/users/userA` and `/users/userB` with the same `/users/**` route, you could try separating those out.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can [wait for an array of aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Aliases), I haven't tried it with multiple calls to the same route, but I think it should do the trick.

```
cy.wait(['@users', '@users'])
```

Comment: Ran the test a dozen times with this change and increased timeout and the issue did not appear. Thanks.

Comment: This throws an error in my case.

Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `requestListings`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: same... tests pass.. but i get a console error `cypress_runner.js:140907 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `config`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.`

Comment: Works as expected without any issues for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've created an example which will blindly wait for all your pending requests to finish before proceeding, you can check the implementation here. https://github.com/PinkyJie/cypress-auto-stub-example#more-detail-for-implementation

Comment: Not upvoting because it does not really answer the question, but interesting script you built there.