# How to capture all API calls in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have API call when loading a chat app, 30 calls/group (it's to load last 30 messages on each group). Let's say in a case, I test a user which has 2 groups only. So I expect to see 60 API calls for this.

I tried with following code.

```
it('Call 30 group messages APIs for every favorite group', () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route(awsUrl + '/**').as('apiMessageContent')

    for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
      cy.wait('@apiMessageContent', { timeout: 30000 }).then(res => {
        expect(res.status).not.to.be.null
      })
    }
  })
```

But the result cypress randomly only can capture 28-30 API calls, and other route waits after that are failing. In fact, in cypress left panel I can see the 60 XHR are all listed. What is the solution for this?

Comment: How long do you expect all 60 of these request to complete in? Is 30 seconds sufficient? Have you tried to increase the timeout to 60?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857888/how-to-wait-for-two-parallel-xhr-requests-in-cypress might be helpful

Comment: Just wondering, is your code capturing the first 28-30 requests, and missing the rest? Or is it catching a sort of random 28-30 requests and missing some between the ones that were caught?

Comment: @CoryDanielson it's waiting first 28-30 requests and missing the rest. looks like other is completed, but cypress doesn't capture them, as if they are not happening.

Comment: @CoryDanielson I don't think adding the timeout will work. If I use `cy.wait(10000)` it will be sufficient to wait all XHRs to be completed.

Comment: So all of the requests are being completed within 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

`cy.wait` can accept an [array of Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Aliases), so you might be able to wait for `@apiMessageContent` in this way, rather than looping and waiting 60 times. Although it's unclear why your solution does not work.

```js
cy.wait(Array(60).fill('@apiMessageContent'), { timeout: 30000 }).then((xhrs) => {
    xhrs.forEach((res) => {
        expect(res.status).not.to.be.null
    })
})
```

Comment: tried your code, only wait up to 21 first API calls

Comment: What if you increase the timeout to 60000?