# Capture all XHR Requests with Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I call the URL, an undefined number of requests are sent.

Now I try to find out if one of the requests contains a certain payload.

```
cy.server();
cy.visit(url);

cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '**/t/e/**',
}).as('xhrRequest');
```

I have found a similar approach on [How to capture all API calls in cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211968/how-to-capture-all-api-calls-in-cypress/57212093#57212093) so far. 
the problem here is that a fixed number of API calls is assumed.

```
cy.wait(Array(60).fill('@xhrRequest'), { timeout: 30000 }).then((xhrs) => {
    xhrs.forEach((res) => {
        expect(res.status).not.to.be.null
    })
})
```

How do I get it that all requests are intercepted and fail my test if there is not a single request containing the payload.

I already wrote something like this in puppeteer

```
let hasSpecialRequest = false; 
page.on('request', request => {
if (isSpecialRequest(request)) {
    hasSpecialRequest = true; 
}
request.continue();
});

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

expect(hasSpecialRequest).to.equal(true);
```

The system checks whether each request is one of the special requests and sets the variable accordingly. Something like this I try to recreate with Cypress.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the problem but since I got here through my Google expedition maybe this might help someone that had my problem and possibly you.

At first I used the `cy.wait(@alias)` but could never retrieve all the responses (only one response was being shown and I couldn't figure out how to access ALL the responses).  So I ended up immediately storing the responses into another array to access within the test.

```
let xhrRequests;

function getXhrRequests() {
    xhrRequests = [];

    cy.intercept('GET', '**', (res) => {
        xhrRequests.push(res);
    });

    return xhrRequests;
}

describe('Some', function () {
    it('Thing 1', () => {
        let thing1 = getXhrRequests();
        cy.visit('http://some.site');
        thing1.forEach((res) => {
            expect(res.status).not.to.be.null;
        })
    }

    it('Thing 2', () => {
        let thing2 = getXhrRequests();
        cy.visit('http://some.site/2');
        thing2.forEach((res) => {
            expect(res.status).not.to.be.null;
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing cy.exec and run a script in another language and return status from subprocess.