# Get different response from same URL

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am working on a React app, where I am using Cypress for testing. My requirements are to compare payload which we are sending in our app and which the ecosystem (DB/backend) has. By using 'Intercept' we can get the request and response from the app, but the issue is we are having same URL with different payload, so every time it's taking only one API and passing the results. Need to get different request and response from APIs. Can someone help with this?

```
cy.intercept({ method: 'POST', url: Cypress.env("URL") }).as('call')
cy.wait('@call').then(({ request, response }) => {
  console.log(request.body,"Hey")
  // console.log(response.body,"body")
  //get dynamically data from json file
  cy.fixture(`kpiId${request.body.kpiId}.json`).then((jsonData) => {
    // Access and use jsonData here
    let json = jsonData
    console.log(json,"jsonnnnn")
    console.log(`kpiId${request.body.kpiId}.json`,jsonData)
    expect(request.body).to.deep.eq(jsonData)
  });
})
```

Comment: It's not clear why there is a problem - `request.body.kpiId` is differentiating the request and you substitute the appropriate fixture, so where is the issue?

Comment: Also, what is the trigger for POST in the app is it form `submit`? How does React send the request.

Comment: the issue is, its only taking one api response regardless of how many apis we are calling

Comment: its not form submit, when the page loads we are sending the requests

Comment: i have written all the intercepts at the start. and then calling cy.wait()

Comment: It still isn't clear what your issue is, but if it is that "I need to wait on my `@call` response multiple times", then this may fix your issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859176/11625850

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok for handling different "payloads" i.e differentiating the response by KPI value in the body.

It will only catch the first KPI if you only have one `cy.wait('@call')`.

The way it works is:

- one `cy.intercept(...).as('call')` to listen to all calls to the *URL-to-be-matched*
- multiple `cy.wait('@call')`, one ***per call*** that occurs.

```js
cy.intercept(...).as('call')

function callHandler = ({ request, response }) => {
  cy.fixture(`kpiId${request.body.kpiId}.json`).then(json => {    
    expect(request.body).to.deep.eq(jsonData)
  })
}

cy.visit(react-app-url)

cy.wait('@call').then(callHandler)  // first KPI
cy.wait('@call').then(callHandler)  // second KPI
cy.wait('@call').then(callHandler)  // third KPI
```

If the app has a regression error and only sends two KPI POST, the third `cy.wait('@call')` will alert you to the fact.

Comment: its taking only one kpi for all cy.wait()

Comment: That means `request.body.kpiId` is the same every call. If you don't expect that, review the network traffic to see what the calls actually are.